# TypeScript: la propiedad outDir de tsconfig.json no me funciona

Tags: typescript

Quiero que lo que compile se agregue a la carpeta `js` , pero se agrega el archivo en la carpeta raíz del proyecto.

Este es mi codigo:

```
{
"compilerOptions":{
  "emitDecoratorMetadata":true,
  "experimentalDecorators":true,
  "module":"system",
  "moduleResolution":"node",
  "noImplicitAny":false,
  "outDir":"js/",
  "removeComments":false,
  "rootDir":"src/scripts",
  "sourceMap":false,
  "target":"ES5"
},
"exclude":[
  "node_modules"
 ]
}
```

Comment: Puedes postear la estructura (carpetas) básica de tu proyecto? Como esta la configuración, TypeScript deberia crear una capeta **`js`** en la raiz de tu proyecto. Entonces, donde quieres que la cree?

Comment: Quiero que la cree en la raiz pero no lo hace lo unico que tengo es un archivo hola.ts,  el tsconfig, la carpeta js vacia porque cuando compila typescript me genera el archvio fuera de la carpeta js me lo coloca en la raiz, es decir me coloca el hola.js en la raiz

Comment: Mauricio, usando el código JSON que proporcionas, efectivamente me crea una carpeta `js` y me coloca el archivo compilado `hola.js` dentro. El archivo `hola.ts`, esta ubicado en `src/scripts`. Esto sobre linux usando **`TypeScript 2.0.3`**. Que sistema operativo estas usando? Que version del compilador **`tsc`** tienes?

Comment: Prueba en colocar **`outDir": "./js"`** y **`"rootDir":"./src/scripts"`**, para decir explícita mente al compilador que las carpetas corren desde la raíz del proyecto.